# Why doesn't my box show?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html/css and did some tutorials on it and tried to add a simple box. It shows the text but not the box around it.

This is my css

```
body
{

background: #6a6a6a;    
background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6a6a6a 0%, #353535 100%);
background-image:  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6a6a6a), color-stop(100%,#353535));
background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6a6a6a 0%,#353535 100%);
background-image:  -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6a6a6a 0%,#353535 100%);
background-image:  -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6a6a6a 0%,#353535 100%);
background-image:  linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6a6a6a 0%,#353535 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6a6a6a', endColorstr='#353535',GradientType=0 );

background-size: auto;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;





.box
{
  background: #fff;
  border: 6px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

}
```

and this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Where do you want to go?</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="box"> why doesn't this show up? </div>

</body>

</html>
```

the "why doesn't this show up should be in a box, but it isn't.

Comment: Is the css curly braces misplacement (none after body, two after box) a copy+paste into the question error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css file do .box, not #box.
`#box` is if you have `id="box"`, `.box` is if you have `class="box"`
Well, you just edited the question, so this is null and void

Ahh, found the problem. Take the .box{} out of the body{}.

Answer (score 0):

1. where is your css if it is in different folder update your `href`
2. try this patern

   ```
   body{
   }
   .box{
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not nested. While it may be your intuition to write something along:

```
#id {
    color: red;

    .box {
        border: 6px solid #ccc;
    }
}
```

it is not valid. You have to do it somewhat tediously:

```
#id {
    color: red;
}

#id.box {
   border: 6px solid #ccc;
}
```

This is why I advise to also look up SASS or LESS.